# trigger updating all rows, not just inserted

Tags: sql-server-2008, spatial

I know I'm missing something obvious here. This trigger is updating all rows in the table (killing performance) when all I want it to do is perform the update on the new inserted row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_location_topo_name]
--fires at each row insert, queries topo map layer (must be present!) and inserts name of topo into new location record
on [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] 
after insert
AS 
BEGIN 
update TBL_LOCATIONS
set TOPO_NAME = dbo.QD24K_GRSM.NAME
FROM dbo.tbl_locations
inner join dbo.QD24K_GRSM 
on TBL_LOCATIONS.Location_ID = TBL_LOCATIONS.Location_ID
WHERE  (QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(TBL_LOCATIONS.SHAPE) = 1)  
END
```

Comment: Please provide your table structures for `QD24K_GRSM` and `tbl_locations` including the primary and foreign keys.

Comment: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046436/can-stwithin-or-stcontains-be-used-to-update-columns-based-on-point-within-polyg[/link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the `INSERTED` pseudo table to get only the rows that were inserted.

Additionally your join condition of `TBL_LOCATIONS.Location_ID = TBL_LOCATIONS.Location_ID` makes no sense at all.

Probably better to do this as an `INSTEAD OF` trigger to modify the rows before insert rather than after they are inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_location_topo_name] 
ON [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] 
INSTEAD OF INSERT 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO TBL_LOCATIONS 
                  (foo, 
                   bar, 
                   TOPO_NAME) 
      SELECT foo, 
             bar, 
             dbo.QD24K_GRSM.NAME 
      FROM   INSERTED I 
             LEFT JOIN dbo.QD24K_GRSM 
               ON QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(I.SHAPE) = 1/* Will insert additional 
                                                    rows if more than one match*/
  END
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is absolutely no column commonality between the two tables, the only possible relationship is spatial, hence the QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(I.SHAPE) = 1 statement. So I'm not clear on how to join the inserted to the QD24K?

Comment: And is there guaranteed to be an exact `1:1` matching record for that condition? If not what should happen if 0 matches or more than one match?

Comment: yes, given the business requirements, there is a finite number of polygons within the spatial table (140), and a location can only occur in within the boundary of one of them. Users are unable to enter locations that do not fall within the bounding box of the polygons.

Comment: 'Cannot create trigger 'update_location_topo_name' on table 'dbo.TBL_LOCATIONS' because an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger already exists on this object.'. I do have another instead of trigger on this table. When I create this trigger as an after insert, inserts fail due to objectid PK constraint violation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create trigger "Instead of Insert" rather than "After Insert".
That way you can modify newly inserted rows as you need before actually inserting them in target table.
And there is absolutely no need to join "inserted" table with target table.

Something like this (syntax might be wrong as not actually run that code):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_location_topo_name]
on [dbo].[TBL_LOCATIONS] 
Instead Of insert
AS 
BEGIN 
    Insert Into TBL_LOCATIONS (...., TOPO_NAME)
    Select ..., CrTable.NAME as TOPO_NAME
        From Inserted Cross Apply 
        (
                Select top 1 QD24K_GRSM.NAME from QD24K_GRSM where 
                QD24K_GRSM.Shape.STContains(Inserted.SHAPE) = 1
        ) as CrTable
END
```